# How to set the mid element when doing a binary search?

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, data-structures

This may sound very naive question. Please excuse me for that. I was working on a problem that involved binary search. And the general way to do that I had learned is

```
 set low = 0, set high = array.Length - 1
 while(low < high)
   mid = (low+high)/2
   if (array[mid] == element) return mid
   if (array[mid] > element) set start = mid +1
   if array[mid] < element ) set high = mid
```

Please note the way i am setting the mid point. But some of example/solution that I saw sets the mid differently and I am not able to wrap my head around that. Please see the code snippet below. Any explanation what does setting the mid = l + (r-l)/2 mean would be greatly appreciated.

```
int BinarySearch(int A[], int l, int r, int key)
 {
   int m;

while( l <= r )
{
    m = l + (r-l)/2;

    if( A[m] == key ) // first comparison
        return m;

    if( A[m] < key ) // second comparison
        l = m + 1;
    else
        r = m - 1;
}

return -1;
}
```

Comment: This question is surely not both in java and C#. Please tag only relevant language

Comment: Are you using Java or c#?

Comment: @notyou I wanted understand the logic for setting the mid point regardless of Java  or c#

Comment: If you’re just looking for logic, no language tag is probably needed. Or pick a specific one. Don’t tag more than one unless absolutely relevant.

Comment: @notyou okay forgive me for the language tag.

Answer (score 2):

The goal in both cases is to find the middle element.

`(low + high) / 2`: The sum of the left and right indices is divided by 2 to get the mid point. The problem with this is that the sum could overflow.
If the sum is an *even* number, we pick the lower one. Example - With left and right as `[2, 5]` - We pick mid as 3

`l + (r - l) / 2`:  The difference between the right and the left index is found and is divided by 2. It is then added to the left index to find the midpoint. It might be easier to visualize this with an example.

Example : `[5, 11]` -> `(11 - 5) / 2 = 3` The middle in this interval is now 3 places or hops from the left index. So, add the left index to find the index of the mid element which is `5 + 3 = 8`

Answer (score 1):

This trick is done to avoid integer overflow problem .

(i)use unsinged right shift operator

```
int mid=(high+low)>>>1
```

or 
(ii)  `int mid=low +(high-low)/2`

`(low+high)/2` will overflow if the sum exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and you will get wrong results or an `RuntimeException`

You can read this article by Josh Bloch: 
https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Comment: thank you Debapriya Biswas. You awesome. That's exactly the explanation I was  looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Middle is equal to the starting index of the left value plus the range between right and left divided by two.

Say our range is 5 to 10.

5 + (10-5)/2 == 5 + 5/2 == 5 + 2.5 == 7.5, the middle of our range